# Write an async method that doesn't call another async method

Tags: c#, async-await

I know how to write an async method that calls other async methods, such as `DownloadFileAsync` or `ReadAsStringAsync`. How do I write one that doesn't use framework's built-in async functionality?

Comment: If the method is not doing any async work, why would you even consider making it async?

Comment: You can just use the Task and wait for it if you want to wait for it to complete.

Comment: @ barisa-puter I want to write my own code that does async work and doesn't depend on the build-in methods.

@ justin-pihony But how exactly do I write the last task down the call chain?

Comment: Well, it depends on *who is doing the work*. Is your method asynchronous because the work is being done by another thread in the same process, or another thread in a different process, or is the work being done on a machine in Japan, or is the work actually writing to an I/O device, or what? Or perhaps the work is being torn up into tiny little pieces and each piece is done on the main thread?  There are lots of ways to do asynchrony. Which do you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean to say that you want to implement your own asynchronous functionality.  Calilng a method asynchronously just means the calling thread is not blocked.  A case where this is useful is when you want to continue to do work while some background action completes.  There are various methods available in the framework that can be executed asyncronously (typically with the convention MethodNameAsync) as you mentioned.  To fire off one of your own methods you can spin up your own thread and have it execute your code.

For example.  [TaskFactory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx) can be used to launch your code by passing it an [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) (delegate).